# Python Selenium - How to click element in pagination that is not a button (<a href="#">›</a>)

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to use Selenium to click the next page button for https://openreview.net/group?id=NeurIPS.cc/2022/Conference#accepted-papers

[Pagination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxtUt.png)
When inspecting, the "button" to navigate to the next page is `<a href="#">...</a>`

```
URL = "https://openreview.net/group?id=NeurIPS.cc/2022/Conference#accepted-papers"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(URL)

WebDriverWait(driver,15)

for i in range(5):
    first_paper = driver.find_element("xpath","/html/body/div/div[3]/div/div/main/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li[1]/h4/a[1]").text
    print(first_paper)


    element = driver.find_element("xpath","/html/body/div/div[3]/div/div/main/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/nav/ul/li[13]/a")
    element.click()

    WebDriverWait(driver,5)
```

It doesn't seem to be able to click the page a second time

```
(selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <a href="#">...</a> is not clickable at point (792, 1230).).
```

I am printing the first paper of each page to make sure it works.

I have also tried this without success:

```
for i in range(3):

    first_paper = driver.find_element("xpath","/html/body/div/div[3]/div/div/main/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li[1]/h4/a[1]").text
    print(first_paper)

    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(("xpath","/html/body/div/div[3]/div/div/main/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/nav/ul/li[13]/a"))).click()

    WebDriverWait(driver,10)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there. With a very slight tweak, I ran your code in my IDE and it worked perfectly fine. Below is the code. **All I did is added `time.sleep(3)` which did the magic. You just had to wait until the page loads before trying to locate desired element.**

```
for i in range(5):
    time.sleep(3)
    first_paper = driver.find_element("xpath","/html/body/div/div[3]/div/div/main/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li[1]/h4/a[1]").text
    print(first_paper)
    element = driver.find_element("xpath","/html/body/div/div[3]/div/div/main/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/nav/ul/li[13]/a")
    element.click()
```

**Result output:**

```
Statistical Learning and Inverse Problems: A Stochastic Gradient Approach
Certifying Some Distributional Fairness with Subpopulation Decomposition
Adversarial training for high-stakes reliability
The Missing Invariance Principle found -- the Reciprocal Twin of Invariant Risk Minimization
MAgNet: Mesh Agnostic Neural PDE Solver

Process finished with exit code 0
```

**Suggestion:**
Do not use absolute XPath(which starts from `/html`). As a best practice always use relative XPath. Absolute XPath will break/stop working easily.

So replace below 2 absolute XPath expressions:

```
/html/body/div/div[3]/div/div/main/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li[1]/h4/a[1]
/html/body/div/div[3]/div/div/main/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/nav/ul/li[13]/a
```

with this relative XPath expression:

```
(//li//h4/a[contains(@href,'/forum?')])[1]
//div[@id='accepted-papers']//li//a[text()='›']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code to navigate through pages:

```
    # Find the pagination list using its CSS selector
    pagination_list = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "ul.pagination")))

    # Find all the pagination numbers 
    pagination_numbers = pagination_list.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")
    
    # Iterate through pagination number and click 
    for page_number in pagination_numbers:
        # Click on the pagination number
        page_number.click()
        
        # Wait for the new page to load before proceeding
        WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.staleness_of(page_number))
```